# How can I decrypt data stored in XML using the XML Encryption Syntax and Processing spec?

Tags: c#, xml, encryption, encryption-symmetric

How could I use C# to decrypt this XML file while I know the password?

```
<EncryptedData xmlns="w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"; Type="w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"; Salt="Gnk/DB61AQ==" IV="iYcfV0NOGy0="> 
<EncryptionMethod Algorithm="w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc"; /> 
<CipherData>
 <CipherValue>/TtgJ46P9L23ZeGt67n+2OZGXoHiGWcUAWE8CdN1Z2aiF40fAg6DfBWGx62RB7Botxr‌​w+f1Jf1CtR10iMLw0iz+VIcbaPFZj5ZfCm3aDeDLbnwXdb7mIdzNtF/5EOjNph/kPz7PxcUlAOUvsLLmj‌​Gtx92EhWL6KpXufKahnRiwLuZLNc</CipherValue>
</CipherData>
</EncryptedData>
```

I tried

```
public static string Decryption(string CypherText, string key) 
{
    byte[] b = Convert.FromBase64String(CypherText); 
    TripleDES des = CreateDES(key);
    ICryptoTransform ct = des.CreateDecryptor();
    byte[] output = ct.TransformFinalBlock(b, 0, b.Length); 
    return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(output); 
}
```

But Exception occurred in

> byte[] output = ct.TransformFinalBlock(b, 0, b.Length); Bad Data

Comment: I have tried 
   public static string Decryption(string CypherText, string key)
        {
            byte[] b = Convert.FromBase64String(CypherText);
            TripleDES des = CreateDES(key);
            ICryptoTransform ct = des.CreateDecryptor();
            byte[] output = ct.TransformFinalBlock(b, 0, b.Length);
            return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(output);
        }
But Exception occurred in >byte[] output = ct.TransformFinalBlock(b, 0, b.Length); Bad Data

Comment: Please update your question with this.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.deltasblog.co.uk/code-snippets/basic-encryptiondecryption-c/

```
  byte[] inputArray = Convert.FromBase64String(input);
          TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tripleDES = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
          tripleDES.Key = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
          tripleDES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
          tripleDES.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
          ICryptoTransform cTransform = tripleDES.CreateDecryptor();
          byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(inputArray, 0, inputArray.Length);
          tripleDES.Clear();
          return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultArray);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `CipherMode.CBC`?

Comment: I receive an error ("Specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm.") in  tripleDES.Key = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);

Comment: and After I changed it with MD5 algo. i receive the error bad data in 
byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(inputArray, 0, inputArray.Length);